# Observable is changed only for one viewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, publish-subscribe

I have collection of `Tags` (array of some string)

For each of `Tags` I create knockout viewModel `TagsViewModel`

```
var TagsViewModel = function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.showTags = ko.observable(false);

  window.shouter.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    vm.showTags(newValue);
  }, vm, 'toggleReviewTags');
}
```

And I have another "toggler" to show/hide tags in another partial view. For it I've created separate viewModel `TagFiltersViewModel` and use knockout pubSub to communicate with `TagsViewModel`

```
var TagFiltersViewModel = function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.isTagsVisible = ko.observable(false);

  vm.isTagsVisible.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    window.shouter.notifySubscribers(newValue, 'toggleReviewTags');
  });

  vm.toggleTags = function() {
    vm.isTagsVisible(!vm.isTagsVisible());
  }
}
```

Each `TagsViewModel` I bind to container with calculated id `"tag-container-"+ {tagId}`
and for each do next thing

```
var element = document.getElementById(tagModel.tagsContainer);
ko.cleanNode(element);
ko.applyBindings(new TagsViewModel(tagModel), element);
```

Problem - locally only one tag from collection is shown after click on toggle button. I have created [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqnqhLh8/), but there I can't reproduce my problem.

Any thoughts what is the problem in my case?

Comment: It's kind of hard to help you out if your fiddle just works as expected... (you forgot to include knockout though). The only error-prone piece of code is the repeated calls to `cleanNode` and `applyBindings`. Al though it's not *wrong*, it's usually best to create a wrapper viewmodel and some `with` or `foreach` bindings to access your separate components.

Comment: @user3297291, knockout I've added as resourse, not from jsfiddle dropdown. And about wrapper - I would like, but in my case it is tricky and is causing some bugs...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like the following, it should make it much easier to manage.

There may be a specific reason you are binding each tag seperately using theapplyBindings method but you'll have to elaborate on that.

```js
var arrayOfTags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  // Return an array TagsViewModels using the map method
  this.Tags = ko.observableArray(arrayOfTags.map(function(tag) {
    return new TagsViewModel(tag);
  }));

  // Observable to track if all tags are hidden/shown
  this.TagsVisible = ko.observable(true);

  // Loop through tags, show and set flag to true
  this.ShowTags = function() {
    self.Tags().forEach(function(tag) {
      tag.Visible(true);
    })
    self.TagsVisible(true);
  };

  // Loop through tags, hide and set flag to false
  this.HideTags = function() {
    self.Tags().forEach(function(tag) {
      tag.Visible(false);
    })
    self.TagsVisible(false);
  };

};

var TagsViewModel = function(name) {
  this.Name = ko.observable(name)
  this.Visible = ko.observable(true);
};

var model = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: ShowTags, visible: !TagsVisible()">Show Tags</button>
<button data-bind="click: HideTags,  visible: TagsVisible">Hide Tags</button>

<hr>

<!-- ko if: Tags() -->
  <!-- ko foreach: Tags -->
    <span data-bind="text: Name, visible: Visible"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```